# Convert word document to Google drive document

Tags: google-drive-api

Im building an application in nodejs that uploads documents to google drive, how can i convert the document to google docs format before uploading it or while uploading it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to specify `convert = true` when doing the insert. See https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert