# Export google drive documents to supported MIME types

Tags: google-drive-api

I am uploading files to Drive using rest api(Version 3), I am able to upload those. But when I try to export that file then I am getting

```
403:Export only supports Google Docs.
```

If I create file on drive editor and then export that, it gets exported properly.
In Version 2 of API I could see there was an option

```
convert=true
```

But in Version 3 there is no such option.

[Stack over Flow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214324/convert-word-document-to-google-drive-document)
But this is for Version 2

Comment: share the http trace. "convert=true" is used when uploading, not when downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [uploading files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_wzxhzdk8wzxhzdk9), you just have to specify the Google docs mimeType for them to be a Drive file.

The documentation gave an example of converting a .csv file in to a Sheets file.

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("My Report");
fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");

java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/report.csv");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/csv", filePath);
File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
.setFields("id")
.execute();
System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

Comment: I understand this is a good workaround. But is there a proper solution to OP's question (ability to convert already uploaded sheets to google docs before downloading through the v3 api)?